# monad tranformers and stacking of multiple monads

Tags: haskell, monads, functional-programming, monad-transformers

I have function `f` with signature `f :: [a] -> StateT Int Reader b [c]`, and `f'` with signature `f' :: a -> StateT Int Reader b [c]`

The computation in f (very simplified) looks like that:

```
f [] = return []
f (s:st) = f' s >>= \x ->
           f st >>= \y ->
           return $ ...
```

And in place of the ... I would like to return the `[c]` part of `x` `++` the `[c]` part of `y` with the monad stuff wrapped around.
Is there a possibility to achieve that without manually unwrapping `x` and `y` and manually put the result together again? Do I need a List monad at the bottom of my monad stack to get simple code? The Reader Monad is obviously not an instance of the MonadPlus class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get what you mean by unwrapping `x` and `y`.

I would have the last line as

```
return (x ++ y)
```

Do I misunderstand what you want?

Comment: oh yeah, you're right - thx :) I mixed up the type of the underlying monad and the result type of the computation.

Answer (score 2):

You can also simply define

```
f = fmap concat . mapM f'
```

(`mapM f' xs` produces a value of type `m [[c]]`, where `xs :: [a]` and `m = StateT Int (Reader b)`, and then `fmap concat` concatenates the lists "inside the monad".)

Answer (score 1):

Both `f' s` and `f st` are values in one monad, namely `StateT Int Reader b`. So you already have `x :: [c]` and `y :: [c]` and you just need to write `return (x ++ y)`, as Dave Hinton said.